# Gaussian Eliminate for GF2 code

Tags: php, gaussian

I have this gauss_eliminate function, but instead of dealing with real numbers, I want it to work on binary values.
I need the GF2 gauss_eliminate function, where the input is binary and the output is binary.
This produces real values, not binary, eg
0.57142857142857
0.71428571428571
-0.42857142857143
-0.28571428571429
0.14285714285714

Gaussian elimination has these 3 allowed steps:
1) Swapping two rows (for achieving a certain look)
2) Multiplying a row by a nonzero number,
3) Adding a multiple of one row to another row.
-- in GF2: addition operation is XOR :  0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+0=1, 1+1=0 --and--
multiplication is AND operation: 0*0=0,0*1=0,1*0=0,1*1=1

```
function gauss_eliminate($A, $b, $N)
{
for ($col = 0; $col < $N; $col++) {
    $j = $col;
    $max = $A[$j][$j];

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $tmp = abs($A[$i][$col]);
        if ($tmp > $max) {
            $j = $i;
            $max = $tmp;
        }
    }

    swap_rows($A, $b, $col, $j);

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $tmp = $A[$i][$col] / $A[$col][$col];
        for ($j = $col + 1; $j < $N; $j++) $A[$i][$j] -= $tmp * $A[$col][$j];
        $A[$i][$col] = 0;
        $b[$i] -= $tmp * $b[$col];
    }
}
$x = array();
for ($col = $N - 1; $col >= 0; $col--) {
    $tmp = $b[$col];
    for ($j = $N - 1; $j > $col; $j--) $tmp -= $x[$j] * $A[$col][$j];
    $x[$col] = $tmp / $A[$col][$col];
}
return $x;
}
```

new code #1, still doesn't work:

```
function gauss_eliminate($A, $b, $N)
{
for ($col = 0; $col < $N; $col++) {
    $j = $col;
    $max = $A[$j][$j];

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $tmp = abs($A[$i][$col]);
        if ($tmp > $max) {
            $j = $i;
            $max = $tmp;
        }
    }

    swap_rows($A, $b, $col, $j);

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
        for ($j = $col + 1; $j < $N; $j++) 
          $A[$i][$j]=( $A[$i][$j] != $A[$col][$j] ) ? 1 : 0;
        $A[$i][$col] = 0;
        $b[$i]=( $b[$i] != $b[$col] ) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
$x = array();
for ($col = $N - 1; $col >= 0; $col--) {
#        $tmp = $b[$col];    
#        for ($j = $N - 1; $j > $col; $j--) $tmp -= $x[$j] * $A[$col][$j];
    $x[$col] = ( $x[$col] != $A[$col][$j] ) ? 1 : 0;
}
return $x;
}
```

New code #2 - still doesn't work - tmp setup to alternate

```
function gauss_eliminate($A, $b, $N)
{ 
for ($col = 0; $col < $N; $col++) {
    $j = $col;
    $max = $A[$j][$j];

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $tmp = abs($A[$i][$col]);
        if ($tmp > $max) { $j = $i; $max = $tmp; }
    }
    swap_rows($A, $b, $col, $j);

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
#            $tmp = $A[$i][$col] / $A[$col][$col];
        for ($j = $col + 1; $j < $N; $j++) $A[$i][$j]=($A[$i][$j] != $A[$col][$j] ? 1 : 0);
        $A[$i][$col] = 0;
        $b[$i] = ( $b[$i] != $b[$col] ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
$x = array();
for ($col = $N - 1; $col >= 0; $col--) {
    $tmp = $b[$col];
    for ($j = $N - 1; $j > $col; $j--) $tmp = 1 - $tmp;
    $x[$col] = ($tmp != $A[$col][$j] ? 1 : 0);
}
return $x;
}
```

Comment: You already know how to apply the multiplication in GF2 correctly, but in the code you still don't use it. What is your problem? Apply the maths or write the code?

Comment: the problem is how to change the code, to replace the lines with tmp and -=

Comment: `-` and `+` should be the same in GF2 and the division is quite pointless, as you only have `0` and `1` inside the matrix. The `+` (or `-`) operation is then simply a `$a != $b ? 1 : 0`

Comment: Thank you Philipp, that is very helpful. Now I get all 1s in the result, so I have a problem somewhere.... I put the new code in the original question above

Comment: after fixing my issue with A[col][col] needing to be A[col][j] (when I got all 1s) I now get a mix of 1 and 0 in the answer, but the answer should be 011010000 and I get instead 0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
1, so I am looking for errors in my code

Comment: still trying to solve this, with code #2 above... no luck

Comment: Can you print an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I found the right syntax. I am getting the right result for one example, after modifying the code in a way that makes sense.... converting - to +, and this + to XOR, while / is ignored and * is AND.
Still it would be nice to get a confirmation that this code is correct.

```
function gauss_eliminate($A, $b, $N) {
for ($col = 0; $col < $N; $col++) {
    $j = $col;
    $max = $A[$j][$j];

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $tmp = abs($A[$i][$col]);
        if ($tmp > $max) {
            $j = $i;
            $max = $tmp;
        }
    }
    swap_rows($A, $b, $col, $j);

    for ($i = $col + 1; $i < $N; $i++) {
#            $tmp = $A[$i][$col] / $A[$col][$col];
#            for ($j = $col + 1; $j < $N; $j++) {
#                $A[$i][$j] -= $tmp * $A[$col][$j];
#            }
#            $A[$i][$col] = 0;
#            $b[$i] -= $tmp * $b[$col];
        $tmp = $A[$i][$col];
        for ($j = $col + 1; $j < $N; $j++) {  
#                $A[$i][$j] = $A[$i][$j] + ( $tmp * $A[$col][$j] );
            $A[$i][$j] = ( $A[$i][$j] != ( $tmp && $A[$col][$j] ) ) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        $A[$i][$col] = 0;
#            $b[$i] = $b[$i]  + ($tmp * $b[$col]);
        $b[$i] = ( $b[$i] != ($tmp && $b[$col]) ) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
$x = array();
for ($col = $N - 1; $col >= 0; $col--) {
    $tmp = $b[$col];
    for ($j = $N - 1; $j > $col; $j--) {
#            $tmp -= $x[$j] * $A[$col][$j];
#            $tmp = $tmp + ($x[$j] * $A[$col][$j]);
        $tmp = ( $tmp != ($x[$j] && $A[$col][$j]) ) ? 1 : 0;
    }  
#        $x[$col] = $tmp / $A[$col][$col];
    $x[$col] = $tmp;
}
return $x;
}
```

The commented text is the old (non GF2 code) as well as my "middle step" of showing where I convert + to XOR, * to AND, etc